# Keyboard keys messed up after installing win 8 pro

Tags: windows-8, keyboard

i have just installed windows 8 pro, and after i test my keyboard all the chars when press shift is messed up, this is my on-screen keyboard looks like[image]

as you can see `@` is swithced with `"` , how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to **Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->Language** and change your language prefrences to UK to US.

Comment: thanks alot man, now it backs to 'normal'

Answer (score 1):

May be [this](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/4050-keyboard-layout.html) would help you. you need to change your Keyboard language from UK to US